Freemius JavaScript Integration for Chrome Extension or React App
I'm trying to integrate the Freemius rest api described in the Apiary but can't even pass the Authentication header generation.
I've wrone a JavaScript code that follows their format to create a signature and their format of authorization code but every time it says that the date stamp is not valid and need to follow their given format.
Here is what I've done,
const crypto = require('crypto');
const axios = require('axios');

function getFreemiusFormattedDate() {
    const currentDate = new Date();

    // Days and months arrays to convert numeric values to names
    const days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
    const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

    // Get day, date, month, year, time (HH:MM:SS)
    const dayName = days[currentDate.getUTCDay()];
    const day = String(currentDate.getUTCDate()).padStart(2, '0');  // Two digits for day
    const monthName = months[currentDate.getUTCMonth()];
    const year = currentDate.getUTCFullYear();
    const hours = String(currentDate.getUTCHours()).padStart(2, '0');  // Two digits for hours
    const minutes = String(currentDate.getUTCMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');  // Two digits for minutes
    const seconds = String(currentDate.getUTCSeconds()).padStart(2, '0');  // Two digits for seconds

    // Combine them into the required format
    const formattedDate = `${dayName}, ${day} ${monthName} ${year} ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds} +0000`;
    console.log(formattedDate);
    return formattedDate;
}

// Example usage
// const freemiusDate = getFreemiusFormattedDate();


// Example usage
const currentTime = getCurrentTimeRFC1123();
console.log(`Current Time: ${currentTime}`);


// Function to generate HMAC-SHA256 signature
function generateFreemiusSignature(httpVerb, contentMD5, contentType, date, canonicalizedResource, secretKey) {
    // Step 1: Build the StringToSign
    const stringToSign = `${httpVerb}\n \n ${contentType}\n ${date}\n ${canonicalizedResource}`;
    // console.log(stringToSign);
    // const stringToSign = `${httpVerb}\n${contentMD5}\n${contentType}\n${date}\n${canonicalizedResource}`;
    // const stringToSign2 = `GET\n \n application/json\n Sun, 16 Feb 2014 21:00:05 +0000\n /v1/developers/135565/plugins.json`;
    // Step 2: Create HMAC-SHA256 hash of StringToSign using secretKey
    const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secretKey);
    hmac.update(Buffer.from(stringToSign, 'utf-8'));

    // Step 3: Generate the signature and encode it in Base64
    const signature = hmac.digest('base64');

    return signature;
}

// Example usage
const httpVerb = 'GET';
const contentMD5 = ''; // If no Content-MD5, leave it empty
const contentType = 'application/json';
// const date = 'Sun, 16 Feb 2014 21:00:05 +0000';
const date = getFreemiusFormattedDate();
const canonicalizedResource = '/v1/developers/20919/token.json';
const secretKey = 'MYSECRETAPIKEY'; // Replace with your actual secret key

const signature = generateFreemiusSignature(httpVerb, contentMD5, contentType, date, canonicalizedResource, secretKey);
console.log(`Generated Signature: ${signature}`);


const scopeEntityId = '12345'; // Your scope entity ID (e.g., site ID, developer ID)
const publicKey = 'MYPUBLICAPIKEY'; // Your public key

const authorizationHeader = `FS ${scopeEntityId}:${publicKey}:${signature}`;
console.log(`Authorization Header: ${authorizationHeader}`);


const url = 'https://sandbox-api.freemius.com' + canonicalizedResource;
const header = {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': authorizationHeader ,
        'timestamp': getFreemiusFormattedDate()   
    }
}


axios.get(url, header)
    .then(response=>{
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(error=>{
        console.log(error.message);
    })

Each time it says I'm not following the given date stamp format. But seems like I did.
What can I try next?
